# Play 2.4.x package play.db.ebean does not exist

Tags: playframework

After creating a new application using activator, I was trying to connect to DB and configured all the necessary steps needed to connect to DB (Following through Play site).

I couldn't succeed and always get this error.

Here is my build.sbt

```html
name := """xxxxx"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

// lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  evolutions
)
libraryDependencies += specs2 % Test

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)


// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

[Updated] Here is my `projects/plugins.sbt`

```html
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Here is my `application.conf`

```html
# Configure Ebean
ebean.default = ["models.*"]

#JPA Configuration
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
 db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
 db.default.username=sa
 db.default.password=""
```

Also is play.db.ebean.Model is deprecated in Play 2.4.x?

I have attached a screen shot of the error.

[image: play.db.ebean does not exist]

[image: package com.avaje.ebean does not exist]

Answer (score 1):

[As announced before](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Ebean-dependency) in 2.4 Ebean is not enabled anymore by default. Fortunately it's still supported and you can enable it easily.

1. In `project/plugins.sbt` uncomment last line:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
   ```
2. In `build.sbt` add `PlayEbean` plugin to `root`:

   ```
   lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
   ```

Also as you noticed now you should use native Ebean's `com.avaje.ebean.Model` instead of `play.db.ebean.Model`

Finally now you should declare a Finder for your models without ID type, so it will be:

```
public static final Finder<Long, Foo> find = new Finder<>(Foo.class);
```

instead of

```
public static final Finder<Long, Foo> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Foo.class);
```

Comment: Thanks @biesior
I changed the library from `play.db.ebean.Model` to `com.avaje.ebean.Model`, still no luck. I do not have any errors throwing in my IDE (IntelliJ) though.

Comment: @user2541141 did you updated the dependencies after adding plugin ? i.e. in working dir: `./activator update` and `./activator compile` ?

Comment: @user2541141and it seems that you didn't uncomment the line with ebean `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")`

Comment: This answer is outdated for 2.5.X version. it should be `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")` https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaEbean

Answer (score -1):

You need to run :
    play idea or activator idea 
    Play eclipse or activator eclipse

You need to regenerate the code for the specific IDEA (Eclipse , intellij) after adding dependencies.